# Django Manage.py Gives No South Commands

Tags: python, django, django-south, database-migration

When I do a "./manage.py help", it gives me NO south commands, although South has been installed.

I have the latest version of south installed for my django project, which is South==0.8.1.

I have added "south" to my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

I have done a manage.py syncdb, and there is a "south_migrationhistory" database table created.

However, when I do a "./manage.py help", it gives me NO south commands.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing south, but I still get no south commands when I do a ./manage.py help

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed South in your virtualenv then, once you are in the virtualenv, try to execute `python manage.py help` instead of `./manage.py help`.

Comment: do you know maybe what is the reason for such situation? I have similar issue on Mac OS X. I run `chmod +x manage.py` before. I use settings in splited configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using virtualenv, ensure that it is activated when running `./manage.py help` command. Django will just pass all import errors when showing available commands.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the INSTALLED_APPS is not overwritten somewhere outside the settings.py file. E.g. if you are using a separate settings file for a local settings.